# MySQL Query result is very slow

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am executing a simple query on a small table

```
SELECT * FROM SYSTEM
```

System table only has three columns(Id, Name, Progress) and 1300 rows.

My code for getting the data is:

```
    try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.107:3306/my_database",
                    username.getText(), password.getText());
            String query = "select * from system";
            stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
            rs = (ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                tableModel.addRow(new Object[] { rs.getInt("Number"),
                        rs.getString("Name"), rs.getFloat("Progress") });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // some other code
        }`
```

This code takes around 15 seconds to display the date in my JTable, while if I execute the query in phpmyadmin it takes less than one second.

Comment: Profile the code or add timing statements to see where the time is being spent.  I think a table named SYSTEM is a bad idea.

Comment: Is it the executeQuery or the time it takes to process the ResultSet that's slow?

Comment: First get the actual time from the beginning of the executeQuery statement and after to determine the actual time spent executing the query.

Comment: I just checked. The execution of the query is fine(~1s), the process of the results set is very slow. Besides using a thread, what should I do for the while loop to finish faster?

Comment: @user3822347 Read my answer. The most important part is probably the last two sentences.

Comment: Although unrelated to the problem at hand, there should be no need to cast to `Connection`, `Statement` or `ResultSet`. Note that there is generally no need to cast to implementation specific classes, the `java.sql` interface are what you should use (and those don't require casting)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [`PreparedStatment`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and I would increase the default [`ResultSet` fetchSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#setFetchSize(int)), and I would limit the query to the three columns (**note** `id` != `Number`) -

```
String query = "select Number, Name, Progress from system";
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
rs.setFetchSize(250);
```

Finally, establishing a Connection like that is probably the wrong way to go for performance. You should look for a Connection pool like [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/) or [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) or [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP).

Comment: I would also add that setting the fetchSize is a trade off against the configured JVM heap size. Might want to consider keeping both in line with one another if the need to change fetchSize periodically arises.

Comment: @Rai For three small columns I might even set it to 1000. Beyond about 50 it's usually only insignificantly faster.

Comment: MySQL JDBC always fetches all rows, unless the fetch size is set to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, see [Connector J implementation notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) under **ResultSet**. Increasing the fetch size for MySQL is useless.

Comment: Additionally, I would recommend tuning your MySQL JDBC configuration a bit as [recommended here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration).

Answer (score 2):

The issue here was likely the

`while (rs.next()) {
    tableModel.addRow(...)`

Each call to [`addRow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow-java.util.Vector-) means a "Notification of the row being added will be generated."

This notification of the `Listener`(s) means quite some overhead. Likely, each call indirectly involves a call to `invalidate` the GUI's state, and more, because the table will have to be redrawn after it changed. Doing that 1300x in ~15s means 100 of those calls per second, which is quite reasonable. The OP should probably look for a way to first gather all data and then update the table model only *once* with all the data. This may mean having to implement his own variation of `DefaultTableModel` or `AbstractTableModel`.